# setuptools to include file in top-level directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

The task is simple: I have a file with extension other than `py`, which needs to be distributed with the package. For the purpose of this example, let's call it `.config.json`.

I tried putting it in `MANIFEST.in` as `include .config.json` - this had no effect.

I tried `package_data={'': ['.config.json']}` - this has no effect either.

I also tried `data_files=[('', '.config.json')]` - this breaks with unrelated error: `error: can't copy '.': doesn't exist or not a regular file`

Short of just writing a build command myself, I cannot find anything I could do to make this work.  And, yes, I've seen tons of similar questions on SO, on GitHub in bug trackers, etc.  I know that both `setuptools` and `distutils` are essentially hopelessly broken, but maybe there is some sensible way to make this work?  I cannot believe that something this simple hadn't been solved yet...

---

As requested, `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages


setup(
    name='project_name',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Project Name in Caps',
    author='My Company',
    author_email=','.join(
        '{}@domain.com'.format(name) for name in
        list_of_names
    ),
    url='https://somewhere',
    packages=find_packages(),
    # package_data={
    #     '': ['.config.json'],
    # },
    # data_files=[('', '.config.json')],
    install_requires=[
        'pytest >= 3.4.2',
        ...
    ],
)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "top-level directory"? Do you want to install the file into `site-packages/` or `site-packages/mypackage/`?

Comment: @phd `site-packages/package-version.egg`

Comment: Are you able to post your `setup.py`?

Comment: @WillKeeling updated with the setup.py.

Answer (score 1):

In `setup.py:

```
package_data={'package': ['../.config.json']}
```

The problem with this approach is that the egg will install `.config.json` into `site-packages/` which is hardly what you want and certainly not what users expect of packages.

PS. `MANIFEST.in` didn't help because it's only for source distribution (`python setup.py sdist`).

Comment: "You need to put the file `.config.json` to `package/`" - No, I don't. It ends up in the wrong place if I do this (instead of `site-package/package-version.egg/.config.json` it is sent to `site-package/package-version.egg/package/.config.json`.)

Comment: OK, this actually did it. Thank you. But, what do you mean by "egg will install" - `egg` is not a program, it's a format.  When I run `setup.py install`, the result is not what you describe. So, what is this about?

Comment: I think I can now answer my own question: `whl` and `egg` formats are incompatible in that how they treat source location.  So, if I run `setup.py install`, It installs correctly, but if I do `setup.py bdist_wheel && pip install ./bdist/*.whl`, I get different results.  I knew Python packaging was garbage, but this is really low...

Answer (score 1):

`data_files` is what you want, but you need to ensure that the filename is enclosed in a list:

```
data_files=[('', ['.config.json'])],
```

That works for me when I run your `setup.py`.